# Going crazy with database query

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

Pardon me for the vague title.  I am having a heck of a time understanding what is going on with a certain database query.  Unfortunately for me, we use this query to make a list of things to do, and tasks are getting dropped for reasons I don't understand.  I have been trying to debug a "mininal" version of my query.

Let me explain what I am trying to find.  Our practice has "exams", which are basically just interactions with a medical practitioner.  We bill for some of these exams, and we keep track of what is billed in our ledger table. (In other words, we do an insert into the Ledger when we process a bill)

Now, if I do the query:

```
 SELECT Patient.PatUnique,
        Exam.ExamUnique,
        Exam.[Date],
        Patient.Last,
        Patient.First

 FROM Patient
 INNER JOIN Exam ON Patient.PatUnique = Exam.PatUnique
```

This results in exactly what you might expect:  a list of patients and dates and ExamUnique numbers (our key in the Exam table).

But if I modify the query like so:

```
SELECT Patient.PatUnique,
       Exam.ExamUnique,
       Exam.[Date],
       Patient.Last,
       Patient.First

  FROM Patient
  INNER JOIN Exam ON Patient.PatUnique = Exam.PatUnique
  WHERE Exam.ExamUnique NOT IN (SELECT Ledger.ExamUnique FROM Ledger)
```

I get *0* records.  On the other hand, I *know* there are `Exam.ExamUnique`s that aren't in the `Ledger` table.  Let's anonymize one as `X`.  I have run:

```
SELECT Ledger.ExamUnique FROM Ledger WHERE Ledger.ExamUnique = X
```

and got no results.  So `X` just isn't in there.

What am I missing?

Here is some sample data, since somebody thinks it will help:

```
Patient.PatUnique      Patient.Last      Patient.First
1                      Smith             Adam
2                      Jones             Sarah

Exam.ExamUnique      Exam.PatUnique      Exam.Date
1                    1                   01012016
2                    1                   01022016
3                    2                   01032016

Ledger.ExamUnique
1
2
```

Expected result of query:

```
Patient.PatUnique  Exam.ExamUnique  Exam.Date  Patient.Last  Patient.First
2                  3                01032016   Jones         Sarah
```

Actual result:

```
0 records
```

Comment: You're missing sample data and the expected output from that data. How are we supposed to figure out what's wrong with your query if we can't produce the conditions to help you debug it? Also, rather than using a NOT IN in your WHERE, you could use an OUTER JOIN and WHERE Ledger.ExamUnique IS NULL. It's much quicker than running a SELECT on each row to satisfy the NOT IN.

Comment: There are HIPAA concerns.  I can't even give the internal keys away.  Is it possible to confirm my logic?

Comment: Outer join and IS NULL is an interesting idea, I'll try that.

Comment: Then make up data.  **Sample** means **sample**, not **excerpts of actual**. I'm quite familiar with HIPAA (I work with medical data in my full-time job); I didn't ask you to provide any PHI.

Comment: @KenWhite: I appreciate your point about sample data, but for some bizarre reason, the OUTER JOIN transform you suggested worked.  The missing records are in there, despite the queries being formally equivalent.  I guess the original version was triggering a database bug.  So thanks for your help.

Comment: No, it's not a database bug. I've used ADS (among other DMBSs) for 20 years (since the Clipper days), and I've been using their SQL since it was introduced. It's not the database. It's in your query, but without sample data I can't explain why your SELECT is wrong. And without sample data, your question doesn't help future readers here, because there's no way to test to see if the same situation applies to them (and no way to post an answer to it).

Comment: I don't understand how logically equivalent queries producing different results isn't a bug.  But I posted fake data for you.

Comment: I hope it was enlightening.

Comment: Not a database bug. See my posted answer (which will be deleted shortly) for a demonstration of why I say it's not.

Answer (score 0):

A commenter very helpfully suggested that I transform my query to:

```
SELECT Patient.PatUnique,
       Exam.ExamUnique,
       Exam.[Date],
       Patient.Last,
       Patient.First

FROM Patient
INNER JOIN Exam ON Patient.PatUnique = Exam.PatUnique
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ledger ON Exam.ExamUnique = Ledger.ExamUnique
WHERE Ledger.ExamUnique IS NULL
```

This is logically equivalent to the original query I was trying to debug, and it works.  Apparently, the first query was triggering a bug in Advantage Database, since logically equivalent queries should produce the same results (but these don't).

A commenter helpfully pointed out that the queries are not quite logically equivalent, since I was implicitly doing a comparison against NULL with the original query.  The new query does an explicit comparison with `IS NULL` so it avoids the undefined behavior that caused a bug with the original query.

Comment: If you are still interested what was wrong then here it is: The problem was due to the the records NULL Ledger.ExamUnique values. If you modify the the query to use `WHERE Exam.ExamUnique NOT IN (SELECT Ledger.ExamUnique FROM Ledger WHERE ExamUnique NOT NULL)` then it will work. You can google the IN/NOT with NULLs if you are interested

Comment: @cha: Thanks, that does make sense.

Comment: How about clearly revising this per the comment & the manual to not incorrectly say it's a bug? Don't just append edits, here giving contradictory statements, rewrite to the best presentation. Adding to something unclear or wrong doesn't make it clear or right.